# Electron.Запуск ncpa.cpl в ОС Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Здравствуйте. Есть ли возможность запустить скрипт `ncpa.cpl` в Windows посредством фреймворка `Electron` ?

Comment: Есть подозрения,что ответ тесно связан с `child_process` и `%windir%\system32\ncpa.cpl`

Answer (score 0):

```
var child = require('child_process').exec;
var executablePath = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\ncpa.cpl";

child(executablePath, null, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Используя возможности Node.js

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('control ncpa.cpl', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```